# How to prove that polynomials are dense in the set of bounded analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $H^\infty$ denote the set of all functions holomorphic and bounded in the open unit disk $\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$, i.e. $\|f\|_{H^\infty} = \sup_{0<r<1} \sup_{\varphi \in [0,2\pi]} |f(re^{i\varphi})|  = \lim_{r \rightarrow 1} \sup_{\varphi \in [0,2\pi]} |f(re^{i\varphi})| < \infty$.

The holomorphy in $\mathbb{D}$ yields that every $f \in H^\infty$ has a representation as power series, i.e. $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k z^k$.

But are polynomials dense in $H^\infty$? To this end, I would try to show  for a given $f \in H^\infty$ that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$ \|f(z) - \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} z^k\|_{H^\infty} = \lim_{r \rightarrow 1} \sup_{\varphi \in [0,2\pi]} |f(re^{i\varphi}) - \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} r^k e^{i k \varphi}| < \epsilon$$

Is this the right approach?

Then I obtain 
$$\|f(z) - \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} z^k\|_{H^\infty} \leq \lim_{r \rightarrow 1} \sup_{\varphi \in [0,2\pi]} \left|\sum_{k=M+1}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} r^k e^{i k \varphi} \right|$$
and here I get stuck.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Your first sentence is kind of a non-starter: In what sense is $f$ defined on the boundary?

Comment: thanks, I corrected the question.

Comment: The closure of the subspace of polynomials is the disk algebra, the space of functions continuous on the closure of the disk and holomorphic on the open disk.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you give me a reference for this?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous on the closed disk, then $$\sup \{ \lvert f(z)\rvert : z \in \mathbb{D}\} = \max \{ \lvert f(z)\rvert : z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}\},$$ so if a sequence of polynomials converges uniformly on the open disk, it converges uniformly on the closed disk.